# WordPress plugin not showing the latest version after SVN commit

Tags: wordpress, svn

Just yesterday i tried committing multiple versions just like i used to before in my plugin. I kept the new tags in tags folder as well however, the changes does not seem to be reflecting.

I already upgraded to version 1.4.6 but the repo is still showing 1.4.3.

First i thought this might be due to latest bugs in the repo however, its still not showing after 2 days.

Anyone know whats going on or what i am doing wrong ? Thanx

**Note: The plugin is updated in svn repo in trunk and tags folder. The changes only are not being reflected in the WP Repo.**

Check: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/inactive-logout/

Link to the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/inactive-logout/

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong Stable Tag version on your Readme.txt file. It should be your plugin version (1.4.6), not WP's (4.7).

See the documentation for “Tag” a new version": https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/

Comment: Thnx for the heads up.. Edited stable tag but the error lies in WP itself.. maybe server faults currently... https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2017/05/11/repository-syncing-issues/

Comment: PS: I was updating an old plugin of mine and changes were online without any delay... Trunk: Version X.  Tags: v.X. Readme Stable Tag: v.X

Comment: Hmm.. yes it was happening for me when i did some versions that day but afterwards it stopped and took time.. and now its updated.. :) Repo is having sync issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue last week. Seems it's some kind of delay. I have recommitted by last weekend and my WordPress plugin page was updated this morning.

Comment: True  .. updated 9 hours it shows https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2017/05/11/repository-syncing-issues/

Comment: Don't leave your signature under your post; those kind of links belong in your user profile. If you do this too often, your posts might get marked as spam.